# Is it possible to sync up LMKs in two Thales PayShield 9000 instances>

Tags: hsm

Basically, when we execute a generate key command such as `A0` then we receive a `key-under-lmk` for future use. What if we have multiple HSMs in a high availability configuration? How would we make sure that all keys-under-LMK mean the same thing to all HSM instances?

The documentation I have doesn't cover this and I didn't find anything online about that particular model.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Yes, Will need to load same LMK in both HSMs in same LMK ID (Default is 00). Normally Thales payShield HSMs doesn't stores keys, if it has same LMK, it will create temporary keys when required and verified.

Comment: Super, thank you! :-) Do you have any info how the LMKs are shared between Thales instances?

Comment: need to load same LMK for all the HSMs.